# Regular Expression to accept only positive number and decimals (only end with .5 .0 or integer accepted)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in JavaScript that will accept only positive numbers and decimals ending with .5 or .0 .

```
(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)
```

This is what I have but I don't know how to change it to reject 0 and 0.0, and reject those ending with .1 .2 .3 .4 .6 .7 .8 .9

```
Accept:
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
1
2
3
4
```

But

```
Reject:
-1.0
-0.5
-0.0
-0.1
-0.7
0
0.0
0.1
0.9
0.4
1.3
1.11
1.51
2.01
```

Comment: Solution from Shay is great `^\d*\.\d{0,}(0|5)`

I forget to include integer in the question
So the final answer would be `(^\d*\.\d{0,}(0|5))|(\d*)`

Comment: Numeric checks should be done with numeric arithmetic, not regexps. Why do you specify the use of a regexp in your question? The correct title would be "Way to check for positive number and decimals (only end with .5 .0 or integer accepted)".

Comment: The regexp you claim is correct matches `1.2345`, yet your question says the "decimal should end with `.5` or `.0`. Does the 5 or 0 need to come immediately after the decimal point, or at the end of a string of digits of any length after the decimal point? Whichever it is, the decimal portion would better be given as an optional portion after the digits before the decimal point, as in `^\d*(\.\d{0,}(0|5))?` so as not to repeat the initial `\d*`. This regexp also matches ".5"; is that something you want to accept? Is `1.` valid too? The regexp you claim is correct also matches "1.59".

Comment: Oh yes, only 5 or 0 need to come immediately after the decimal point.
Only 1 decimal point is accepted.
Seems like "1.59" still can pass the Validation.

Comment: *Seems like "1.59" still can pass the Validation.* Do you mean that it passes this regexp but should not, or that it passes this regexp and that accepting it is correct? In the latter case, the phrasing "ends with" in your question is misleading.

Comment: It should not pass.

Comment: The answer you accepted is wrong, because it accepts `0.51`. I guess that shows the importance of designing test cases properly.

Comment: In case you didn't see, the answer was changed several hours ago to reflect rejecting 0.51.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this here at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hZ1bE5/7). The regex I used to do this is:

```
(^0\.5$)|(^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[05])?$)
```

What is highlighted in blue is a match.

Comment: This works, but I'm still wondering why one would use regexps to do numerical checks, although granted the OP did specify regexps, which is much like specifying using a shoe to pound in a nail.

Comment: @torazaburo, I agree. Which is why I personally like your solution, because it is easy to use and more versatile. +1 to you

Comment: How about 0?
"0" can pass the above regex

Comment: @Jbisgood9999999, I'm assuming you don't want it to pass the regex?

Comment: Sorry for the missing case, but i hope it can also handle "0" as rejected result. 
Sorry for case not detail enough

Comment: @Jbisgood9999999, I modified this so that 0 is a rejected result. You can see in the updated link.

Comment: Thank you so much :) You and the regex101 helps a lot, i must bookmark this. You make my day!

Comment: This fails on `0.51` (erroneously reports true). That's just one example of why it's a bad idea to use regexps for numerical assertions. Also, your regexp does not seem very elegant, with the special-casing of `0.5`, the duplication of th `^` start-of-string anchor, etc.

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that case too. Yeah, in order to capture this in a regex, it seems like it's going to be quite a chore. Guess this is really the direction the OP wants to go.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the number by 2 and see if it is an integer:

```js
function check(v) {
  return v > 0 && !(v*2 % 1);
}

var tests = [
  0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  -1.0, -0.5, -0.0, -0.1, -0.7, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.4, 1.3, 1.11, 1.51, 2.01];

tests.forEach(v => console.log(v, check(v) ? "passes": "fails"));
```

Comment: Regular expressions are over-used, written not read, and wrong due to poor assumptions. (for example, using a comma as the fraction separator is common in Europe, "0,5"; adding characters (whitespace, commas, underscores, etc) as digit grouping separators, using exponential notation,  leading + or - sign, etc. This is the only correct answer I see on this page. That and it's probably way faster than any pass through the regular expression state machine.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regular expression: `^\d*\.\d{0,}(0|5)`  ?

Here is the explanation:

```
^         //line start
\d*       //any number (or none) occurrences of any number
\.        //decimal dot
\d{0,}    //0 or more digits (actually the same as * - you can use it here too)
(0|5)     //ends with 0 or 5
```

Comment: It works great. I think i need to update my question.
1.0 2.0 is accept, how about Integer? Sorry but i know nothing about javascript or regex... Thanks, i will update my question

Comment: Oh cool, i fix it with
`(^\d*\.\d{0,}(0|5))|(\d*)` by adding `|(\d*)` Thank you so much for you explanation, it helps a lot.

Comment: You've left off the anchor on the end, so that it will match "1.59".

Comment: @ehsan Well, this answer was written before the OP edited his question to call for accepting "1".

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var patt = /^(\+)?\d+(\.[05])?$/;
            var number = 1.5;
            if (number > 0 && patt.test(number))
                alert("Number is valid");
            else
                alert("Number is Invalid");
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This accepts `0.0`, which is supposed to be rejected. Also, why would you use `(\.0|\.5)` instead of just `(\.[05])`?